# How to set Fade in or Fade out on <a-sky>

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, virtual-reality

Is possible to add fade in or fade out animations on a sky in aframe?

How can I add animations when the user hovers their cursor over the ball?

In this example when you hover your mouse, the background will change but w/o animations.

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('set-sky', {
  schema: {
    default: ''
  },
  init() {
    const sky = document.querySelector('a-sky');
    this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      sky.setAttribute('src', this.data);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/b813db0614ac2b518e547105e810b5b6eccfe1c8/dist/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-camera position="0 2 4">
    <a-cursor color="#4CC3D9" fuse="true" timeout="10"></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>

  <a-sphere color="#F44336" radius="1" position="-4 2 0" set-sky="https://c3.staticflickr.com/2/1475/26239222850_cabde81c39_k.jpg"></a-sphere>

  <a-sphere color="#FFEB3B" radius="1" position="4 2 0" set-sky="https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1688/25044226823_53c979f8a1_k.jpg"></a-sphere>

  <a-sky></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use CSS as demonstrated in the answer above. A-Frame generally doesn't use CSS, but relies on its own display components and properties.

You can fade by animating the `material.opacity` of the `<a-sky>` primitive. This can be done either by using the A-Frame core [`<a-animation>`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/animations.html), or the [`aframe-animation-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component), which seems to be becoming the standard.

If you use the [`aframe-animation-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component), which I recommend, you could set up your `<a-sky>` like this:

```
 <a-sky src="#sky-1"
     animation__fadein="startEvents: fadein; property: material.opacity; from: 0; to: 1; dur: 1000;"
     animation__fadeout="startEvents: fadeout; property: material.opacity; from: 1; to: 0; dur: 1000;"></a-sky>
```

Then within your custom component, you would trigger the `startEvents` for each animation using `emit` (e.g., `sky.emit('fadein')`).

I forked your code and made a few changes:

- Updated A-Frame version to the official release
- Uploaded sky images to a CDN to avoid CORS issues
- Defined aforementioned images as assets for better loading
- Set a default image for `<a-sky>`
- Added the [`aframe-animation-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component)
- Converted ES6 features such as `const` and arrow functions to `var` and `function`, respectively, for better compatibility (to rule out any misbehaving)
- Used `setTimeout` in your custom `set-sky` component to time the animations. Although, you may want to depend on events instead, which can get more complicated with multiple listeners. I just wanted to give you a rudimentary example.

**Here is the modified demo: https://codepen.io/dansinni/pen/gzbpWy**

There's actually also an example right on the A-Frame site that does pretty much what you're looking to do: https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/

Comment: thanks for the answer.
do you know what transition effect / animations is used by google map 360?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately. Maybe try a doing a crossfade (fading one out while simultaneously fading the other in) rather than doing the fades in sequence.

Comment: can you help me do that? i'm still confused

Answer (score 0):

try to add this:

```
HTML:
  sky.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-animation:opac 6s linear forwards";
  sky.setAttribute("style", "animation:opac 6s linear forwards";
CSS:
  @-webkit-keyframes opac {
      0% {opacity: 0;}
      100% {opacity: 1;}
  }
  @keyframes opac {
      0% {opacity: 0;}
      100% {opacity: 1;}
  }
```